# c# one Form blocking another in a winform Project

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, blocking

I have an application which uses 2 forms, a Main Form and a Splash Form being used in the following configuration:

```
public class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
       SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen();

       // configure Splash Screen
    }
}


public class SplashScreen
{
    public SplashScreen()
    {
       InitializeComponent();

       // perform initialization

       this.ShowDialog();
       this.BringToFront();
    }
}
```

NB: Main form is created with the following code:

```
Application.Run( new MainForm() );
```

The problem above is that the configuration of splash does not occur unless splash is closed with

```
splash.Close();
```

only when this occurs does the rest of the MainForm constructor run. how can I easily stop this blocking behaviour?

Comment: Seems like the error is likely inside your SplashScreen constructor. Can you post that code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already replied to you with a working example on the other question you asked for the same thing:

[C# winforms startup (Splash) form not hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510765/510786#510786)

Comment: Apologies. This is a different problem to the above question, although you are correct in saying your solution might work for this problem as well. I will have to give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you need to show splash screens on a separate thread, and let the primary thread carry on with loading. Not trivial - in particular, you will need to use `Control.Invoke` to ask the splash screen to close itself when ready (thread affinity)...

Answer (score 0):

Use splash.Open() rather than splash.OpenDialog() and this won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to just show you splash form, but not let it block the main form.

Here's how I've done it:

```
class MainForm : Form {

    SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen();  //Make your splash screen member

    public MainForm()
    {
        splash.Show();  //Just show the form
    }

}
```

Then in your MainForm_Load you do your initialization as normal.

Now when your form is ready to be displayed (MainForm_Shown):

```
public MainForm_Shown()
{
    splash.Close();
}
```

This lets your MainForm load normally while displaying the splash screen.