# Force WinForms Application.Run method to use WPF form

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading, winforms

I have an existing WinForms application. 
In this application one form is called in separate thread:

```
 var newDialogThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ShowMyForm));
 newDialogThread .Name = "CustomerViewThread";
 newDialogThread .IsBackground = true;
 newDialogThread .ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA;
 newDialogThread .CurrentCulture = Config.CustomerCulture;

public void ShowMyForm()
{
  using(var myForm = new MyForm())
  {
     Application.Run(myForm );
   }
}
```

Now customer wants to use WPF form instead of WinForms dialog.  Application will stay Winforms based.

How properly to refactor this part of code so my WPF form will be called instead of Winforms?

```
 public void ShowMyForm()
    {
      using(var myWpfForm = new MyWpfForm())
      {
          // Analog of Application Run?
         //Application.Run(myForm );
       }
    }
```

P.s. I think that its possible to create pure WPF window without hosting it to Winforms. And this is main case.

Comment: How about creating your window and showing it as a dialog?

Comment: It is not called a form in WPF.

Comment: @Omribitan i am not sure that it will be enought. In any case application.Run do something so i dont think that i shoud just remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer in the related thread:
[How do I create and show WPF windows on separate threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111369/how-do-i-create-and-show-wpf-windows-on-separate-threads)

```
  private void NewWindowHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{       
    Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadStartingPoint));
    newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
    newWindowThread.Start();
}

private void ThreadStartingPoint()
{
    Window1 tempWindow = new Window1();
    tempWindow.Show();       
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to edit your (`WinForms`) `MyForm` control to add an [`ElementHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) control into it, so that it can host your WPF control:

```
MyWpfForm myWpfForm = new MyWpfForm();
ElementHost elementHost = new ElementHost();
elementHost.Child = myWpfForm;
this.Controls.Add(elementHost);
```

In this way, you can leave your `ShowMyForm` method unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://weblogs.asp.net/jdanforth/archive/2008/07/29/open-a-wpf-window-from-winforms.aspx) explains how to do it. But basically:

1) Create/Add a new project of type "WPF Custom Control Library"

2) Add a new Item of type "Window (WPF)"

3) Do your thing with the WPF Window

4) From your WinForms app, create and open the WPF Window:

```
using System;  
using System.Windows.Forms;  
using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;  

//Place the following code where you want to open the WPF window
var wpfwindow = new WPFWindow.Window1(); 
ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(wpfwindow); 
wpfwindow.Show();
```