# can't open Window in callback method wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, sockets, user-interface

When open Window in callback method of socket.BeginReceive , display error :  The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.

```
int id = pr.ReadInt32();
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter();
if (!InCall)
{
   string name = null;
   Incoming_Call IncmCall = new Incoming_Call();
   InCall = (bool)IncmCall.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create and show WPF windows on separate threads?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111369/how-do-i-create-and-show-wpf-windows-on-separate-threads)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ***Dispatcher.BeginInvoke*** to force UI thread to open a new window