# Why does the thread run only once - open and close windows?

Tags: c#, multithreading, xaml, task

I am trying to open the "Loading" window while logging into the program. Everything works correctly only once. The second time I run it, I get the error: System.InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because it belongs to another thread. Please help...

ViewModel.cs

```
private ProszeCzekaj proszeCzekaj;

private async void ZalogujExecute(object obj)
{
    try
    {

        Thread tbr = new Thread(() =>
        {
            proszeCzekaj = new ProszeCzekaj();
            proszeCzekaj.Closed += (sender2, e2) =>
                proszeCzekaj.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
            proszeCzekaj.Show();
            Dispatcher.Run();
        });
        tbr.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);  //required for WPF
        tbr.Start();

        var odp = await SprawdzLogowanie();
        if (odp==1)
        {
            
        }
        proszeCzekaj.Dispatcher.Invoke(proszeCzekaj.Window2Close);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

async Task<int> SprawdzLogowanie()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        AplikacjaDbContext db = new AplikacjaDbContext();
        foreach (var user in db.UsersTable.ToList())
        {
            MessageBox.Show(user.userLogin); //for test
        }
    });
    
    return 1;
}
```

Logowanie.xaml.cs

```
namespace PGSQL.View
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logika interakcji dla klasy Logowanie.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public delegate void dWindow2Close();
    public partial class Logowanie : Window
    {
        public Logowanie()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            LogowanieViewModel model = new LogowanieViewModel();
            this.DataContext = model;
        }
    }
}
```

Loading.xaml.cs

```
namespace PGSQL.View
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logika interakcji dla klasy ProszeCzekaj.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ProszeCzekaj : Window
    {
        public dWindow2Close Window2Close;

        public ProszeCzekaj()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Window2Close = new dWindow2Close(SecondWindowClose);

            IntPtr hWnd = new WindowInteropHelper(GetWindow(this)).EnsureHandle();
            var attribute = DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE.DWMWA_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE;
            var preference = DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE.DWMWCP_ROUND;
            DwmSetWindowAttribute(hWnd, attribute, ref preference, sizeof(uint));

            ProszeCzekajViewModel model = new ProszeCzekajViewModel();
            this.DataContext = model;
        }

        private void SecondWindowClose()
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        public enum DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE
        {
            DWMWA_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE = 33
        }

        // The DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE enum for DwmSetWindowAttribute's third parameter, which tells the function
        // what value of the enum to set.
        // Copied from dwmapi.h
        public enum DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE
        {
            DWMWCP_DEFAULT = 0,
            DWMWCP_DONOTROUND = 1,
            DWMWCP_ROUND = 2,
            DWMWCP_ROUNDSMALL = 3
        }

        // Import dwmapi.dll and define DwmSetWindowAttribute in C# corresponding to the native function.
        [DllImport("dwmapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, PreserveSig = false)]
        internal static extern void DwmSetWindowAttribute(IntPtr hwnd,
                                                         DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE attribute,
                                                         ref DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE pvAttribute,
                                                         uint cbAttribute);
    }
}
```

Comment: As here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111369/how-do-i-create-and-show-wpf-windows-on-separate-threads , it might require to add `tbr.IsBackground = true;` (before `tbr.Start();`), but I'm just guessing

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately still the same error. Visual Studio selects exactly this line in ViewModel.cs - `proszeCzekaj.Show();` - as causing the error

Comment: Please post the exception stack trace and the code which calls `ZalogujExecute`. Also, by "second", do you mean a completely separate application instance, or is this code called twice in the same app?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your request 100% correctly, but... Call Stuck `> PGSQL.exe!PGSQL::ViewModel::LogowanieViewModel::<<ZalogujExecute>b__33_0>d::MoveNext()` and code `proszeCzekaj.Show();`. `ZalogujExecute` is binding command on button in xaml. In ViewModel `public PGSQLCommand Zaloguj { get; set; }` and `Zaloguj = new PGSQLCommand(ZalogujExecute, ZalogujCanExecute);`

Comment: As a test, I replaced Logowanie.cs with the following code:
`private void Zaloguj_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Thread tbr = new Thread(() =>
    {
        br = new ProszeCzekaj();
        br.Closed += (sender2, e2) =>
            br.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
        br.Show();
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
    });
    tbr.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);  //required for WPF
    tbr.Start();
}

private void Anuluj_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    br.Dispatcher.Invoke(br.Window2Close);
}`
:-( same error

Answer (score 0):

It is expected that the [Show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.show) method will throw an exception if reused.

> [InvalidOperationException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.invalidoperationexception)
> [Show()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.show) is called on a window that is closing ([Closing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.closing)) or has been closed ([Closed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.closed)).

If you want to reuse a window, it may better:

- to have `SecondWindowClose` call [Hide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.hide) rather than `Close`
- to prevent the user from closing `ProszeCzekaj`,  maybe using [WindowStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.windowstyle)