# display an intermediate screen in the transition from screen 1 to screen 2

Tags: c#, winforms

How to display an intermediate screen in the transition from screen 1 to screen 2

Screen 2 contains a table with a database that takes some time to display. Switching between screen 1 and screen 2 The software disappears until Screen 2 opens. How can I post a message to the user "Please wait ..."

this my code:

```
this.Hide();
Form C = new Main();
C.ShowDialog();
this.Show();
```

i work on C# , WinForm

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I show a "Loading . . . please wait" message in Winforms for a long loading form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918158/how-do-i-show-a-loading-please-wait-message-in-winforms-for-a-long-loadi)

Answer (score -2):

You can use [Thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?view=netframework-4.7.2). Start your Thread before ShowDialog and run below-shown method within that thread. To close that thread you need to use Thread Form's [Shown Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.shown?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2). So that you can close thread after form successfully shown to the user. It is mandatory to close your thread.

```
    private static LoadingForm loadForm;

    static private void ShowForm()
    {
        loadForm = new LoadingForm();
        Application.Run(loadForm);
    }
```

This **loadForm** object should have your loading image in the background-image property of form.

I am showing minimal code so that you can do rest of the task by yourself. It's good if you do something by yourself. Beware of how to handle cross-thread exception whenever using Thread.

Hope this makes help.

Comment: Please provide an explanation for any negative marking.