# BringToFront() does not work

Tags: c#, winforms, z-order

I have a winform project with a splash form (as described in the first answer of this question : [C# winforms startup (Splash) form not hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510765/c-winforms-startup-splash-form-not-hiding)).

When I use this splashform the mainform loose the focus. I want to bring it to the front as soon as I close the splashform with Form.BringToFront() but it does'nt work.

Anybody can help?

Comment: Once the splash form closes, the main form should automatically get focus again.  Where is the focus going??

Comment: Avoid reinventing that wheel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392864/c-splash-screen-problem

Answer (score 4):

Raymond Chen just [addressed this issue](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/23/10052986.aspx) with Win32 programs in his blog today.

Basically, you need to show your main form and call BringToFront on it before closing your splashscreen.