# GIF Animation not working in Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics, picturebox

### I have 2 WinForms

Form2 uses Infragistics ultraTabControl.
On Tab Changing im Showing Form1.

### In Form1

I have a `PictureBox` assigned with animated `GIF`

### In Form2

I am displaying Form1 like this.

```
Form1 frmOne=new Form1();
frmOne.Show();
```

### Problem

`GIF` is not playing animation.

Comment: you are constructing your froOne incorrectly. It should be "new Form1()" instead on "new Form()". Compiler should give you an error.

Comment: @ToKa sorry.it is "new Form1()" only.

Comment: share some code for your prcoess, if still having some problem.

Comment: A gif will not animate when the UI thread is busy with something else.  Your code snippet gives no clue what it might be busy with.  Post code that reproduces the problem.  Use BackgroundWorker to offload busy work to another thread.

Comment: @aWebdesigner09 If the behavior is temporary I would recommend doing performance profiling to see what is preventing the UI from updating when showing your form.  If you have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate you can do this with the profiling tools: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx  Does the animation start after a delay or does it not show because it is removed after the tab switches?

Comment: for animated an image you can use this controller.
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1004624/Gif-viewer-Snipper-control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solved

My current Thread is busy to Play GIF Animation.

I tried So many ways like Application.DoEvents(); etc.
But every thing can't helped me.

The answer in the following Question, which uses Threading is a very great working idea.

[StackOverFlow: Show/Hide Splash Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510765/c-sharp-winforms-startup-splash-form-not-hiding/510786#510786)

Thanks for every one.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you have your image in the image property *NOT THE BACKGROUND IMAGE PROPERTY*. That's the mistake I made

Answer (score 4):

It is working fine for me. I have just dragged a new pictureBox on form and setting image property at Form_Load() event and showing GIF animated.

I did same as you on button click:

```
  TestForms.NavBarTest newForm = new TestForms.NavBarTest();
            newForm.Show();
```

At my Test Form:

```
private void NavBarTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = NavronChartControl.Properties.Resources.url;
        }
```

Note: If your picture box is disabled then it will not animate the Gif

Reference:
 [How do you show animated GIFs on a Windows Form (c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165735/how-do-you-show-animated-gifs-on-a-windows-form-c)
[Animated Progress Indicator in C# (Windows Forms)](http://trompelecode.com/2010/12/animated-progress-indicator-in-csharp-windows-forms/)

Try to implement using this link:[Animated GIF in picturebox won't animate](http://www.debugging.com/bug/18530) apprach.

Comment: thanks for ur answer. I tried out a sample. Its working. But its not working in My App. Iam just edited the question. Please refer that.

Comment: My form was disabled. Your comment helped me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to achieve it is to run the animation in an async task, but accordingly, some limitations are possible to do that on windows form using:

`System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(int milliseconds)`.

*My splash view is displayed with a gif (loading)*

e.g.: In your constructor,

```
public partial class MainMenu : Form
{

    private SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen();

    public MainMenu ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            splash.ShowDialog();
        });

       Thread.Sleep(2000);
   }
```

It is imperative to put the `Thread.Sleep(int)` after starting a new one, don't forget that every action you did on this thread needs to be invoked, for example:

```
    void CloseSplash()
    {
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
        {
           splash.Close();
        }));
    }
```

Now your gif should work!

Answer (score 0):

This question has already raised before.
Though the approach is different but the questions concept is the same

[StackOverFlow: How do you show animated GIFs on a Windows Form (c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165735/how-do-you-show-animated-gifs-on-a-windows-form-c)

Source project where you can use [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24044/AJAX-style-Asynchronous-Progress-Dialog-for-WinFor)

I guess that will help you out

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and came across different solutions by implementing which I used to face several different issues. Finally, below is what I put some pieces from different posts together which worked for me as expected.

```
    private void btnCompare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadStart threadStart = new ThreadStart(Execution);
        Thread thread = new Thread(threadStart);
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
    }
```

Here is the **Execution** method that also carries invoking the PictureBox control:

```
    private void Execution()
    {
        btnCompare.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { pictureBox1.Visible = true; });
        Application.DoEvents();

        // Your main code comes here . . .

        btnCompare.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { pictureBox1.Visible = false; });
    }
```

Keep in mind, the PictureBox is invisible from **Properties Window** or do below:

```
private void ComparerForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If none of the previous answers work for you, another idea is to refresh the image tag or write it on the fly with jQuery.
In my case I needed to show an animated GIF when a button on the form was clicked.  Previously it would show up but not animate.  I just added a jQuery event when the button was clicked that added the image tag on-the-fly to a div through the parent tag's html() function.

```
$('.showhidegif').html("<img src='/Content/img/angled-spinner.gif' />");

<div class="col-sm-12 showhidegif"></div>
```

Worth a shot especially if you're already using jquery on your page.